# i wrote one simple shell script using nested while loop but i got a error where iam trying to decrementing "b" values and incrementing "a" values

Tags: shell

I am trying to increment and decrement a variable values in a while loop in each iteration.

I have provided the error below which I am getting.

```
******0 ./test1.sh: line 8: [: expr $b - 1: integer expression expected
./test1.sh: line 4: [: expr $a + 1: integer expression expected******
```

```sh
while [ "$a" -le 10 ]
do

  b="$a"
  while [ "$b" -ge 0 ]
  do
   echo -n "$b "
   b='expr $b - 1'
  done

   a='expr $a + 1'

done
```

Comment: `b='expr $b - 1'` sets `b` to the literal string `expr $b - 1`, which is not an integer.  You probably meant to write `b=$(expr $b - 1)` and `b=$(expr $b + 1)`  But there are better ways to write that.

Answer (score 0):

You're mistakenly using single quotes to wrap `expr $a + 1`. Doing so, `$a` will not expand to the value of `a`. The double quotes will let `$a` expand, instead.

Simple demonstration of the problem: at a terminal, type `a=1` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then type `echo 'a is $a'` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, to see that the terminal prints literally `a is $a`. Then do it again, but this time the command is `echo "a is $a"`, and you'll see the terminal prints `a is 1`.